# how to properly use sklearn to predict the error of a fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I'm using `sklearn` to fit a linear regression model to some data. In particular, my response variable is stored in an array `y` and my features in a matrix `X`.

I train a linear regression model with the following piece of code

```
    from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X,y)
```

and everything seems to be fine.

Then let's say I have some new data `X_new` and I want to predict the response variable for them. This can easily done by doing

```
    predictions = model.predict(X_new)
```

My question is, what is this the error associated to this prediction?
From my understanding I should compute the mean squared error of the model:

```
    from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
    model_mse = mean_squared_error(model.predict(X),y)
```

And basically my real predictions for the new data should be a random number computed from a gaussian distribution with mean `predictions` and sigma^2 = `model_mse`. Do you agree with this and do you know if there's a faster way to do this in `sklearn`?

Comment: I don't think I agree. Wouldn't you agree that the real predictions are `predictions` themselves? The performance of the model is computed by comparing predictions made on `X_new` with their corresponding known targets `y_new`.

Comment: N.B. you could also compute the R-squared score simply by running `model.score(X_new, y_new)`.

Comment: I agree with you and I do indeed compute the R-squared score to select my best model. The thing is that once you come up with your best linear model you have to associate an error to your predictions.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to validate your model on your training data set. I would suggest exploring the cross-validation submodule [`sklearn.cross_validation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.cross_validation).

The most basic usage is:

```
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Comment: Thanks, I do that already. The problem is after I validate the model and pick the best-fitting parameters, what is the error associated with the predictions?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you training data- 
If it's distribution is a good representation of the "real world" and of a  sufficient size (see learning theories, as [PAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probably_approximately_correct_learning)), then I would generally agree.

That said- if you are looking for a practical way to evaluate your model, why won't you use the test set as Kris has suggested?
I usually use grid search for optimizing parameters:

```
#split to training and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test =train_test_split(
X_data[indices], y_data[indices], test_size=0.25)

#cross validation gridsearch 
params = dict(logistic__C=[0.1,0.3,1,3, 10,30, 100])
grid_search = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid=params,cv=5)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

#print scores and best estimator
print 'best param: ', grid_search.best_params_ 
print 'best train score: ', grid_search.best_score_
print 'Test score: ', grid_search.best_estimator_.score(X_test,y_test)
```

The Idea is hiding the test set from your learning algorithm (and yourself)- Don't train and don't optimize parameters using this data.

Finally you should use the test set for performance evaluation (error) only, it should provide an unbiased mse.